# How to make a POST request using CustomVision api with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, botframework

I'm trying attach an image using the bot emulator tool and sending this image off to the microsofts customvision api, the issue I'm having is that I get

`{ Code: 'BadRequestImageFormat', Message: '' }`

back from custom the custom vision api call.

I'm using the the `request` module from `npm` to handle the calls

```
// Receive messages from the user and respond by echoing each message back (prefixed with 'You said:')
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("Hello"); //session.message.text
    // If there is an attachment

    if (session.message.attachments.length > 0){ 
        console.log(session.message.attachments[0])
        request.post({
            url: 'xxx',
            encoding: null,
            json: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'Prediction-Key': 'xxx'
            },
            body: session.message.attachments[0]
        }, function(error, response, body){
            console.log(body);
        });
    }
});
```

I believe that I may be sending the wrong format through to custom vision however I have been unable to figure it out as of yet.

Comment: Can you add more details about the image you used (which is the image format, the image size...).
Did you tried directly to use Custom Vision with your image first?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your issue and it looks like the problem is your 'Content-Type'. You're attempting to pass JSON in your request, but setting the content-type as `octet-stream`. See my modified code below:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
  session.send("Hello"); //session.message.text
  // If there is an attachment
  if (session.message.attachments.length > 0){
    console.log(session.message.attachments[0])
    request.post({
      url: 'https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures',
      encoding: null,
      json: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'Your API Key...'
      },
      body: session.message.attachments[0]
    },
    function (err, response, body) {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      console.log(body);
    });
  }
});
```

When I run this, I get the error `InvalidImageUrl` which is to be expected as it's looking for a content on localhost. You could get round this by exposing your localhost using [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).